# multiples loops with conditions inside

Tags: php, for-loop, calendar

I'm building a weekly calendar application based in "layers". This calendar is a matrix based on Day-Hour represented in $calendar variable as array:

```
hour |Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday ...
12am
01am
02am
...
```

If a want to apply holidays to calendar I do:

```
$holidays = getHolidays();
for( $day = 0; $i < count($calendar)); $day ++)
{
    for( $hour = 0; $i < count($calendar[$day])); $hour ++)
    {
        if ( exists_in_array( $calendar[$day][$hour] ,  $holidays ) )
        {
            $calendar[$day][$hour] = "holiday";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I want to apply set special event I do:

```
$specialDates = getSpecialDates();

for( $day = 0; $i < count($calendar)); $day ++)
{
    for( $hour = 0; $i < count($calendar[$day])); $hour ++)
    {
        if ( exists_in_array( $calendar[$day][$hour] ,  $specialDates  ) )
        {
            $calendar[$day][$hour] = "special";
        }
    }
}
```

At this moment, I am so worried because having a loop to iterate the calendar in order to apply a new layer could make the application more slow and slow.

So, is it a good practice (in my case) to add different information to my calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the same set of loops instead of looping though them multiple times?

```
$specialDates = getSpecialDates();
$holidays = getHolidays();
for( $day = 0; $i < count($calendar)); $day ++)
{
    for( $hour = 0; $i < count($calendar[$day])); $hour ++)
    {
        if ( exists_in_array( $calendar[$day][$hour] ,  $specialDates  ) )
        {
            $calendar[$day][$hour] = "special";
        }
        if ( exists_in_array( $calendar[$day][$hour] ,  $holidays ) )
        {
            $calendar[$day][$hour] = "holiday";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm well, my question was oriented to the number of loops and conditions. I mean, suppose I have 100 layers and 50 conditions. Should I have only one loop with 60 conditions inside or keeping 100 loos with one condition inside?

Comment: Personally if I am going to be looping through the same information over and over, I try to just run the loop once. Also just an FYI you shouldn't put an operation in your for loop like count($calendar[$day]) you should really move this otherwise it recounts every single time it goes through the loop.